# Hide/Show many elements on single click by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I've code few line of jQuery for *Hide/Show* many elements on single click and it's working. But problem is; i've many more image class items, *so my script going to long, my question is how to simplify or make short my script, i mean any alternatives or any new idea? please suggest*.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="choose-color">
<span>
 <i class="images-red" style="">Red Image</i>
  <i class="images-blue" style="display: none;">Blue Image</i>
   <i class="images-pink" style="display: none;">Pink Image</i>
 <!-- many many images -->
</span>

 <button class="red">Red</button>
  <button class="blue">Blue</button>
   <button class="pink">Pink</button>

</div>
```

**JS:** [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/455k1hhh/) >

```
$("button.red").click(function(){
    $(".images-red").show();
    $(".images-blue, .images-pink").hide();
});
$("button.blue").click(function(){
    $(".images-red, .images-pink").hide();
    $(".images-blue").show();
});
$("button.pink").click(function(){
    $(".images-red, .images-blue").hide();
    $(".images-pink").show();
});
```

Please suggest for short and simple code of my script. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by adding just a common `class` to those buttons,

```
var iTags = $("#choose-color span i");
$("#choose-color button.button").click(function(){
    iTags.hide().eq($(this).index("button.button")).show();
});
```

The concept behind the code is to bind click event for the buttons by using the common class. Now inside the event handler, hide all the `i` elements which has been cached already and show the one which has the same index as clicked button.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/455k1hhh/1/)

For more details : [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`.index(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector)

And if your elements order are not same, both the `i` and button's. Then you can use the `dataset` feature of javascript to over come that issue.

```
var iTags = $("#choose-color span i");
$("#choose-color button.button").click(function(){
    iTags.hide().filter(".images-" + this.dataset.class).show()
});
```

For implementing this you have to add data attribute to your buttons like,

```
<button data-class="red" class="button red">Red</button>
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/455k1hhh/10/)

Comment: Works, what is the `eq` any documentation of uses?

Comment: @Aariba Actually `eq` will help you to access the element collection in an indexed manner. Just like an array. I have attached the doc in the answer. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
  $("#choose-color button").click(function(){
        var _class = $(this).attr('class');
        $("#choose-color i").hide();
        $(".images-"+_class).show();
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/455k1hhh/5/

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be the prettiest solution, but it should do the job.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var classname = $(this).attr('class');
    $("#choose-color span i").hide();
    $(".images-"+classname).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following using `data-*` attributes, because when you have more elements of the same color, using index of the button won't work. And simply using the whole `class` attribute won't work if you have to add more classes to the button in future.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var color = $(this).data('color');
  var targets = $('.images-' + color);
  targets.show();
  $("span i").not(targets).hide();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="choose-color">
  <span>
<i class="images-red">Red Image</i>
<i class="images-blue hidden">Blue Image</i>
<i class="images-pink hidden">Pink Image</i>
<!-- Many many image -->
</span>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button data-color="red">Red</button>
  <button data-color="blue">Blue</button>
  <button data-color="pink">Pink</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense to have all images share a single class (`.image` for example).  Then you just use a shared class for the button and the image; in this example I used the color name.  Now, when any button is clicked, you can grab the class name of the image you want to show.

Give this a try:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".image").hide();
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
    $("." + className).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/><br/>
<div id="choose-color">
<span>
<i class="image red" style="">Red Image</i>
<i class="image blue" style="display: none;">Blue Image</i>
<i class="image pink" style="display: none;">Pink Image</i>
<!-- Many many image -->
</span>
<br/><br/>
<button class="red">Red</button>
<button class="blue">Blue</button>
<button class="pink">Pink</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making future extensibility a little difficult this way due to relying on class names but this would solve your immediate need:

```
<div id="myImages">
  <i class="images-red" style="">Red Image</i>
  <i class="images-blue" style="display: none;">Blue Image</i>
  <i class="images-pink" style="display: none;">Pink Image</i>
  <!-- Many many image -->
</div>
<div id="myButtons">
  <button class="red">Red</button>
  <button class="blue">Blue</button>
  <button class="pink">Pink</button>
</div>
```

```
$("#myButtons button").click(function(){
        var color = $(this).attr("class");
    var imageClass = ".images-"+color;
    $('#myImages').children("i").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(imageClass).show();
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/455k1hhh/9/)

**Edit:** Note how I wrapped the buttons and images in parent divs to allow you to isolate just the buttons/images you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<div id="choose-color">
<span>
<i class="images-red" style="">Red Image</i>
<i class="images-blue" style="display: none;">Blue Image</i>
<i class="images-pink" style="display: none;">Pink Image</i>
<!-- Many image -->
</span>
<br/><br/>
<button class="colour red" onclick="myFunction(this)">Red</button>
<button class="colour blue" onclick="myFunction(this)">Blue</button>
<button class="colour pink" onclick="myFunction(this)">Pink</button>

</div>
```

JS: [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/455k1hhh/#&togetherjs=GDBOdwG8zJ)

```
$(".colour").click(function(){
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "pink"];
    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        if($(this).hasClass(colors[i])){
            $(".images-"+colors[i]).show();
        }else{
            $(".images-"+colors[i]).hide();
        }
    }
});
```